# Chrome extension background.js file reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**EDIT**

My chrome extension calling an api service in the background.js file and i can get the data. But after closing the browser window, i cant get the data from the api service in background.js file. It showing null value. When go to the chrome://extensions/ and reload the extension I can get the data.

When close the browser window, the data fetched is being reset and when open the browser, data not fetching. Data can be fetched from the api only after reloading the extension.

Why happening so. Does any one have an idea about this?

This is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "32": "images/icon32.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "name": "Test",
  "short_name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "build/background-bundle.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": [
      "build/content-bundle.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }], 
  "options_ui": {    
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true 
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/algo://nlp/SummarizeURL/0.1.1; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: what does "next version" mean above?

Comment: and where in the above are you "passing some additional data based on the user login id'

Comment: Next  version means - the next version of extension. https://sample-api-call will fetch the data based on the user cookie.

Comment: sample-api-call is being fetched in the background script. Chrome extension background scripts don't share cookies with the browser tabs, so I don't think that part will work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923344/does-chrome-extension-has-its-own-document-cookie for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can't reload the background file based on anything other than reopening the browser or reloading the extension manually. What you should instead do is have a content script tell background.js to run `getTaxonomyList` again when the user log in happens.

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.userLoggedIn) {
       getTaxonomyList().done(function(list) {
          sendResponse(list);
       });
    }
})
```